# How to set up Ajax with Struts 2?

Tags: java, ajax, struts2

According to articles like:

http://www.oreillynet.com/onjava/blog/2007/06/easy_ajax_with_struts_2.html

and

http://www.firstpartners.net/kb/index.php/Easy_Ajax_using_Struts_2

it should be easy (out of the box) to use Ajax with Struts 2, but all of the examples leave out details.  Does anyone know of any tutorials that include all the code I would need for an example program?

I am very comfortable with Struts 2, but I'm totally new to Ajax, and my JavaScript is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those pages are a bit old. I believe that at present the most recommended way is using the [struts2-jquery](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery-plugin/) plugin.

Comment: Wow, the documentation there is even worse than the others.  Do you know of any examples that show both the Java code and the JSP?

Comment: You can look at the showcases (in "external links"), the source for them is available in the "download" tab.